# How to add Slide navigation drawer on existing UiViewController programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

how can i add the slide navigation drawer in an existing app on  blank uiviewcontroller  programatically in ios thanks in advance.. such as on tap of navigation bar item slide drawer to be shown

Comment: Try [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu#installation) for side navigation drawer.

Answer (score 1):

View the sidebar menu tutorial. Very nice and easy to use
https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/